# How can I make a predicate with this?

Tags: sql, ios, subquery, nspredicate

I have a languages entity that stores text and the language code it goes with. I need to get the list of all the text for the language the user has selected, unless a particular line of text isn't available in that language, in which case I need to get the English version.

My table is basically like this, in SQL terms:

```
DECLARE TABLE Languages
(
    textId int,
    languageCode char(2),
    text varchar(2000)
)
```

With both textId and languageCode as my primary key.

In SQL, I would basically do this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(l.text, e.text)
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM Languages WHERE languageCode = 'en') t
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM Languages WHERE languageCode = @selectedLanguage) l
    ON l.textId = t.textId
```

That should give me exactly 1 piece of text for each textId; using English if it can't find the selectedLanguage.

Is it possible to do anything like this using NSPredicate and a FetchedResultsController? I found a little info on the SUBQUERY keyword, but no real explanation of how to use it with an NSPredicate.

Comment: See my blog post: ["What the heck is SUBQUERY?"](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2726166818/what-the-heck-is-subquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was able to do this in a different and much simpler way...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"language.languageCode == %@ OR
    (language.languageCode = 'en' AND NOT (question IN %@))", languageCode, foundLanguages]
```

Where foundLanguages is an array of all the text that I have in the selected language. It does require an extra fetch request to get the list of all text for the selected language, but it returns exactly what's needed. MUCH simpler than using the left-join and subqueries like I was thinking in SQL. Probably less efficient though.